# How to make DropDownList control not mandatory

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In mvc project,I have some optional values so need to correspondent control must not be mandatory.

**Property is**

```
[Display(Name = "Transaction type")]
public int TransactionTypeID { get; set; }
```

Razor syntax for control is

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.TransactionType, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-3">
     @Html.DropDownList("TransactionTypeID", null, "Select tran", new { @placeholder = "Select tran type", @class = "form-control" })
      </div>
    </div>
```

Controller syntax to fill the control

```
private void LoadTransactionTypesInViewData(object selectedValue = null)
{
    var datas = transactionTypeRepository.GetAll().OrderBy(p => p.Name);
    ViewBag.TransactionTypeID = new SelectList(datas, "TransactionTypeID", "Name", selectedValue);
}
```

Why my drop down list mandatory, why not it optional.How to make it optional.

Comment: Because is typeof `int` (and `int` must always have a value). If you want to have the option of a `null` value, make it `int?` (nullable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your property allow null. You can do by either way. Although int? is just shorthand for Nullable, which itself is shorthand for `Nullable<Int32>`

```
[Display(Name = "Transaction type")]
public Nullable<int> TransactionTypeID { get; set; }
```

### or

```
[Display(Name = "Transaction type")]
public int? TransactionTypeID { get; set; }
```